# ¿Como puedo recuperar informacion de un RAID1 con un disco dañado?

Tags: data, hardware

Tengo un inconveniente con unos discos que estaban en RAID1, uno de los discos se daño y el otro contiene la informacion en espejo, el problema es que al querer recuperar la informacion, no detecta los archivos (o los detecta, pero con otro formato), y utilizando programas de recuperacion, no reconoce toda la informacion, ahora la idea es clonar el disco utilizando un aparato llamado Manhattan QuickDock Duo, mi pregunta viene a ser la siguiente:

Al realizar esta operacion, es posible remover el RAID1?

Si es posible, como puedo realizarlo?